# Refactoring Code to RxJava, Looping locations and arraylist

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm still learning RxJava, I know the basic what is Observable & Observers,
But still confused how, where & when to use filter, map, flatmap, etc

Do you have any good suggest how to convert this code to RxJava ?

```
void locationChanged(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
        Double lat = location.getLatitude();
        Double lng = location.getLongitude();

        boolean isMock;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
            isMock = location.isFromMockProvider();
        } else {
            isMock = !Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0");
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < offices.size(); k++) {
            Office office = offices.get(k);

            Double d_lat = Double.valueOf(office.getOc_lat());
            Double d_long = Double.valueOf(office.getOc_long());
            Double d_radius = Double.valueOf(office.getOc_radius());

            Location.distanceBetween(lat, lng, d_lat, d_long, resultApi);
            String s_distanceToOffice = String.valueOf(resultApi[0]);
            Double d_distanceToOffice = Double.parseDouble(s_distanceToOffice);
            //Log.e(TAG, "locationChanged: Distance -> " + d_distanceToOffice);

            // check-in in radius
            if (d_distanceToOffice < d_radius) {
                buttonOutOfRadius.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progressBarPosition.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonRecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // checking fake gps
                if (isMock) {
                    processTheMock();
                } else {
                    in_area = "Y";

                    site_name = office.getOc_site();
                    site_id = office.getOc_id();
                    site_lat = office.getOc_lat();
                    site_long = office.getOc_long();

                    processNoMock(lat, lng, site_name);
                }
                stopLocationUpdates();
                break;
            }

            else if (d_distanceToOffice > d_radius) {
                progressBarPosition.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                buttonOutOfRadius.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonRecord.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

    }
    stopLocationUpdates();
}
```

Which code needs to be changed and unnecessary to change ?
What I've done like this :

```
Observable.fromIterable(offices)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe()
```

do i need to just copy paste the code inside looping "for(..) into "oNext(Office office)" ?

It's nice to know from your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days i got the the good flow to refactor it into Rx,

Here my code in kotlin, easy to read, if you have any better alternative for this, please share to me

```
private fun locationChanged(locationResult: LocationResult) {
    for (location in locationResult.locations) {

        val lat = location.latitude
        val lng = location.longitude
        var dDistanceToOffice: Double
        var dRadius: Double

        Observable.fromIterable(offices)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .filter {
                    val dLat = it.oc_lat!!.toDouble()
                    val dLong = it.oc_long!!.toDouble()
                    dRadius = it.oc_radius!!.toDouble()

                    // Check the distance "MyLocation" to "OfficeLocation"
                    Location.distanceBetween(lat, lng, dLat, dLong, resultApi)
                    val sDistanceToOffice = resultApi[0].toString()
                    dDistanceToOffice = sDistanceToOffice.toDouble()

                    dDistanceToOffice < dRadius
                }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object : Observer<Office> {
                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                        disposable = d
                    }

                    override fun onNext(office: Office) {
                        inArea = "Y"
                        siteName = office.oc_site
                        siteId = office.oc_id
                        siteLat = office.oc_lat!!
                        siteLong = office.oc_long!!
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "locationChanged() Error: ${e.message}")
                    }

                    override fun onComplete() {
                        // checking the data in Area = N or Y
                        if (isMock(location)) {
                            processTheMock()
                        } else {
                            if (inArea == "Y") {
                                hideButtonOutRadius()
                                hideProgressbarPosition()
                                showButtonCheckin()
                                processNoMock(lat, lng, "In Radius", siteName!!)
                            } else {
                                retrofitGoogleGeocoding(lat, lng)
                                inArea = "N"
                                siteName = newAddress
                                siteLat = lat.toString()
                                siteLong = lng.toString()
                                hideButtonOutRadius()
                                hideProgressbarPosition()
                                showButtonCheckin()
                                processNoMock(lat, lng, "In Radius", siteName!!)
                            }
                        }
                        stopLocationUpdates()
                    }
                })
    } // end of location
}
```